# How to retrieve the controller class from within a view/helper in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

I know about `controller_name` returning a string containing the controller's name but how can I retrieve the controller class (or object) from within a helper?

**EDIT:** The solution should also work when the controller is namespaced (eg. `Admin::PostsController`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `constantize` method, like:

```
controller_name.constantize
```

Though I'm not sure how it will behave if you have a namespaced controller.

**Update:**

That one won't work for all controller names and/or namespaces. Though one can use the `#controller` method in combination with `#class`:

```
controller.class
```

Comment: `controller_name` is not helpfull cause the `Admin::PostsController` returns simply `posts`. Constantizing it would return `Posts` which is not enough to retrieve the controller.

Comment: You're right! I just tested `controller.class` in a view and it seems to work, even namespaced. Mind trying?

Answer (score 1):

In pure Ruby, because class names are constants, you can do this to get the class from a string:

```
classname = 'Posts'
p Kernel.const_get(classname).methods
```

There is a nice shortcut in Rails, `constantize` for just this:

```
p 'Posts'.constantize.methods
```

If the classname is eg 'editable_file', first call the `camelize` method:

```
p 'editable_file'.camelize.constantize  # EditableFile
p 'extensions/editable_file'.camelize.constantize  # Extensions::EditableFile
```

EDIT: If you really want to get the controller name un-demodulized, then this code in `config/initializers/controller_name.rb` should ensure it:

```
class ActionController::Metal
  def self.controller_name
    # @controller_name ||= self.name.demodulize.sub(/Controller$/, '').underscore
    @controller_name ||= self.name.sub(/Controller$/, '').underscore
  end
end
```

Comment: But where would I get the string from to constantize, eg "Admin::PostsController"?

Comment: who gave that answer -1 ? this is valid and good information for everyone who'd like to know a little more. and the string, vrinek, you get from 'controller_name' as you stated in your question.

Comment: Tampering with Metal will break some stuff cause we already use the untampered `controller_name` method in many parts of our application.

Answer (score 1):

A view probably shouldn't need to do this. Ideally whatever you're trying to do in the view that expects this, you would instead do in the controller.

Trying to think about why you'd want to do this, the best answer I can think of is that you want to invoke a helper method you've defined in the controller. There already exists a construct to do this, use [helper_method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.2/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method).

For pretty much anything else, the controller should provide that data to the view. Not the view pulling it out of the controller. (e.g. even though you shouldn't need the class, the controller could provide it with `@controller_class = self.class`, which would then be available to the view)

Comment: Yeah, but you might need to use `controller_name` in your helpers. Eg I have a user_nav helper that uses controller_name to determine when to print authentication links